# JSP Servlet Overriding Resource Bundle from Property Files in External Path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, resourcebundle

Iam using JSP/Servlet Application.
I want to override the ResourceBundle as i have the Properties in external path(not inside war). 
I am not able to access the ResourceBundle in the JSP.

My ResouceBundle Name is ApplicationResources.properties. I have Properties for other locale as well.
In JSP, the fmt tags are as shown below

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
   <fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" />
```

In Web.xml, the following configuration is used for JSTL

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>ApplicationResource</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The Following MyResourceBundle is not executed when application starts. Is there any configuration needs to be added in web.xml?

```
    public class MyResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {
    public MyResourceBundle(){
            File file = new File("C:\\Prop"); 
            ClassLoader loader=null;
            try {
                URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};  
                loader = new URLClassLoader(urls); 
                ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationResources", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
                setParent(bundle);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { 
                System.out.println("RESOURCe EXCEP");
            }
    }

@Override
protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
      return parent.getObject(key);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
     return parent.getKeys();
}
```

}

Is there any error in above code?
Is it possible to override the resourcebundle in JSP/Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on resource bundle base name states:

> This is the bundle's fully-qualified resource name, which has the same form as a fully-qualified class name, that is, it uses "." as the package component separator and does not have any file type (such as ".class" or ".properties") suffix.

So, your bundles base name should be `MyResourceBundle` if you want to use your class.

If you specify the `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext` context parameter in your web.xml, you don't need to set the bundle on each page.